# append textbox value to form action url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search form and I need to pass the keyword into the URL. I know using the GET method is much easier but for some reason when I use it nothing happens. It doesn't move to the action URL. But the POST method works for me.

So what I need to do is when a user types in a keyword it automatically needs to be appended to the form action URL so I can grab it when the user submits the form. I need to pass it to the URL.

Below is what I have done so far:

```
<script>
    $('#input-search').on('change', function (event) {
        var myVal = $(this).val();
        $('form').attr('action', function(i, value) {
            return value + "&search=" + myVal;
        });
    });
</script>

    <form action="http://loclahost/index.php?route=catering/search" method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="input-search" name="keyword" />
      <input type="submit" name="search" value="search"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Problem is on each change you are appending &search to previous action url

Comment: GET query parameters should not be in the POST URL (*action*). If you want to pass additional parameters with the POST, use hidden inputs.

Comment: I think you should use an AJAX call or $.post() method

Answer (score 0):

```
var formAction =  $('form').attr('action');
$('#input-search').on('change', function (event) {
    $('form').attr('action', formAction+ "&search=" + this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `keyup` instead of `change` and also grab default attribute `action`  and use it

```
$val = $('form').attr('action');
$('#input-search').on('keyup', function (event) {
    var myVal = $val
        + "&search=" + $(this).val();
  $('form').attr('action', myVal);
});
```